# How Do Implement Depth First Search Into This Code?

Tags: graph, stack, depth-first-search

Struggling a bit here. I would like to implement a depth first search, this is an adjacency list graph. Fully working but I'm a little clueless on implementing a search like this. Do I need to add a stack class before I begin to DFS? Any help would be great!

```
class vertex:
    def __init__(self, label, edges = []):
        self.id = label
    self.edges = []

class graph(vertex):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = {}

    def addVertex(self, label):            
        self.vertices[label] = vertex(label)
        return self.vertices              

    def addEdge(self,frm,to):
        self.vertices[frm].edges = self.vertices[frm].edges + [to]
        return self.vertices

    def dot(self):
        for v in self.vertices:
            for e in self.vertices[v].edges:
                print "%s -> %s;"%(v, e)

    def viewVertLink(self):
        for v in self.vertices:
            print ""
            print "Vertex:","(",v,")"
            for e in self.vertices[v].edges:
                print "%s -> %s;"%(v, e)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    g = graph()

    for i in range(10):
        str(g.addVertex(i))

    str(g.addEdge(0,1))
    str(g.addEdge(0,2))
    str(g.addEdge(1,3))
    str(g.addEdge(1,4))
    str(g.addEdge(2,3))
    str(g.addEdge(3,5))
    str(g.addEdge(4,5))
    str(g.addEdge(4,6))
    str(g.addEdge(6,7))
    str(g.addEdge(7,1))
    str(g.addEdge(7,8))
    str(g.addEdge(8,9))
    str(g.addEdge(9,0))


    print "digraph G{"
    g.dot()
    print "}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to help more than just give pseudo-code but I do not quite understand the language you are using. But quick run down on the implementation

```
Get a stack
mark your source as visited and push to stack
while stack is not empty
retrieve element on top of stack without removing it
Go through its adjacent nodes
if you find a node that has not been visited
mark it as visited and push into stack
repeat from source, except this time with the new item
else if all adjacent vertices have been visited pop the stack
```

Here is a java implementation

```
void dfs(int adjacency_matrix[][], int source){
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int numNodes = adjacency_matrix[source].length -1;
    boolean [] visited = new boolean[numNodes +1];
    visited[source] = true;
    stack.add(source);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        int current = stack.peek(); // don't remove the element but get it
        System.out.println("Current node being visited is "+current);
        for(int x = 0; x <= numNodes; x++){
            if(adjacency_matrix[current][x] == 1 && visited[x] == false){
                visited[x] = true;
                stack.push(x);
                break;
            }else if(x == numNodes){
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your high level is helpful actually thank you! The language is Python if you have any experience in it?

Comment: Not quite @S.Clusker but if you can follow this implementation you should be able to get it right. Please mark my answer as correct or vote up if it does help. If you have any questions please ask. Thank you.

Comment: No problem dude, the theory is all the same regardless of language, i appreciate that!